# Prolog POST handler

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

i'm pretty new to Prolog and i have some troubles with POST.
This is my Prolog form:

```
form([action='/game', method='POST'], [
              p([], [
                label([for=fromX],'From X'),
                input([name=fromX, type=textarea])
              ]),
              p([], [
                label([for=fromY],'From Y'),
                input([name=fromY, type=textarea])
              ]),
              p([], [
                label([for=toX],'To X'),
                input([name=toX, type=textarea])
              ]),
              p([], [
                label([for=toY],'To Y'),
                input([name=toY, type=textarea])
              ]),
              p([], input([name=submit, type=submit, value='Submit'], []))
            ])
```

and this is my handler:

```
answer('/game', Request) :-
 memberchk(search(Search), Request),
 memberchk(toX=ToX, Search),
 memberchk(toY=ToY, Search),
 memberchk(fromX=FromX, Search),
 memberchk(fromYy=FromY, Search),
 whiteTurn(ToX/ToY, FromX/FromY, White_N),
 game_page(White_N).
```

When I hit submit button, I get

> Internal server error goal unexpectedly failed

Can someone please help me with how to make this handler work properly? Now I only need to proceed data from form to `whiteTurn` function, I will deal with other exceptions later.

Here is executable example, with same error:

```
:- use_module(library('http/thread_httpd')).
:- use_module(library('http/html_write')).
:- use_module(library('http/http_session')).
:- use_module(library('http/http_error')).

server :-
  server(3000).

server(Port) :-
  http_server(answer,
        [ port(Port),
          timeout(20)
        | []
        ]).

 answer(Request) :-
  memberchk(path(Path), Request),
  answer(Path, Request).

 answer(/, _Request) :-
   title_page.

 answer('/game', Request) :-
  memberchk(search(Search), Request),
  memberchk(toX=ToX, Search),
  memberchk(toY=ToY, Search),
  memberchk(fromX=FromX, Search),
  memberchk(fromYy=FromY, Search),
  whiteTurn(ToX/ToY, FromX/FromY, White_N),
  game_page(White_N).

  title_page:-
   reply_html_page(
        title('Draughts'),
        [
         h1('Draughts'),
   form([action='/game', method='POST'], [
          p([], [
            label([for=fromX],'From X'),
            input([name=fromX, type=textarea])
          ]),
          p([], [
            label([for=fromY],'From Y'),
            input([name=fromY, type=textarea])
          ]),
          p([], [
            label([for=toX],'To X'),
            input([name=toX, type=textarea])
          ]),
          p([], [
            label([for=toY],'To Y'),
            input([name=toY, type=textarea])
          ]),
          p([], input([name=submit, type=submit, value='Submit'], []))
        ])
    ]).

 whiteTurn(X/Y, A/B, WHITE_N):-
  WHITE = [ 2/1,4/1,6/1,8/1,
    1/2,3/2,5/2,7/2,
    2/3,4/3,6/3,8/3],
  M = [ 1/1,2/1,3/1,4/1,5/1,6/1,7/1,8/1,
    1/2,2/2,3/2,4/2,5/2,6/2,7/2,8/2,
    1/3,2/3,3/3,4/3,5/3,6/3,7/3,8/3,
    1/2,2/2,3/2,4/2,5/2,6/2,7/2,8/2,
    1/4,2/4,3/4,4/4,5/4,6/4,7/4,8/4,
    1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5,5/5,6/5,7/5,8/5,
    1/6,2/6,3/6,4/6,5/6,6/6,7/6,8/6,
    1/7,2/7,3/7,4/7,5/7,6/7,7/7,8/7,
    1/8,2/8,3/8,4/8,5/8,6/8,7/8,8/8 ],
    (   member(X/Y, M), (X =:= A + 1; X =:= A - 1), Y =:= B - 1, 
    member(A/B, WHITE) ->  
    delete(WHITE, X/Y, WHITE_M), WHITE_N is [A/B|WHITE_M]; 
    WHITE_N = WHITE ).

    game_page(White_N):-
     reply_html_page(
        title('Draughts'),
        [
         h1('Draughts'),
     form([action='/game', method='POST'], [
          p([], [
            label([for=fromX],'From X'),
            input([name=fromX, type=textarea])
          ]),
          p([], [
            label([for=fromY],'From Y'),
            input([name=fromY, type=textarea])
          ]),
          p([], [
            label([for=toX],'To X'),
            input([name=toX, type=textarea])
          ]),
          p([], [
            label([for=toY],'To Y'),
            input([name=toY, type=textarea])
          ]),
          p([], input([name=submit, type=submit, value='Submit'], []))
        ])
      ]).
```

Comment: Please change this to a minimal and **complete** example that we can try out!

Comment: This might help you get a better idea what is going on: http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/Developing.html

Comment: @mat I added executable examle of my code with same error

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks, i will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the precise cause of **failure** in Prolog programs, use the powerful technique of **declarative debugging**.

To do this, add the following definition to your program:

```
:- op(950,fy, *).

*_.
```

Now, using `(*)/1` lets you *generalize away* goals in a very convenient way, by simply using `*` in front. This amounts to commenting the goal out, but is more convenient because it also works for the last goal of a clause, without having to change `,` to `.` in the preceding goal.

So, in your case, a quick look confirms that the failure occurs in `answer/2`. Logically, failure means that your program is **too specific**. Thus, you can *generalize* it for example like this:

```
answer('/game', Request) :-
  * memberchk(search(Search), Request),
  * memberchk(toX=ToX, Search),
  * memberchk(toY=ToY, Search),
  * memberchk(fromX=FromX, Search),
  * memberchk(fromYy=FromY, Search),
  * whiteTurn(ToX/ToY, FromX/FromY, White_N),
  game_page(White_N).
```

I am using <s>strikethrough</s> font to indicate that the goal can be simply *discarded* when reading this snippet.

If you try it now with the thus modified program, it **succeeds**!

Obviously, though, the program is now much **too general**.

So, you can again make it more specific by systematically re-introducing the goals you have generalized away.

Here is a first shot:

```
answer('/game', Request) :-
  memberchk(search(Search), Request),
  * memberchk(toX=ToX, Search),
  * memberchk(toY=ToY, Search),
  * memberchk(fromX=FromX, Search),
  * memberchk(fromYy=FromY, Search),
  * whiteTurn(ToX/ToY, FromX/FromY, White_N),
  game_page(White_N).
```

Here, I have (arbitrarily) re-introduced the *first* goal.

Now, the whole query again **fails**!

Thus, we have found a definite **cause** of this failure: To make the whole query succeed, we must either introduce additional clauses, or *generalize* this particular goal.

In other words, this all means: A term of the form `search(S)` *does not occur* in `Request` in this case!

I leave correcting this as an exercise.

If you are ever unsure what the actual `Request` contains, you can use this definition instead to emit the request:

```
answer('/game', Request) :-
        format("Content-type: text/plain~n~n"),
        maplist(portray_clause, Request).
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, but my main problem is that i have no idea how to take variables from my post form and put them into whiteTurn statement. Now i know that they are not even in Request, but don't know why. I was searching for solution on internet, but i haden't find any. Nowhere is some simple solution how to do it.

Comment: I figured it out, i had to use GET method instead of POST, then i could pass my data to other page. Thanks for help, your code was helpfull for finding my mistake :-)

Comment: It's perfectly ok to use the `POST` method, and in some cases it is even necessary or better. However, you need to handle the request differently, please see the [documentation](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=http-read-post). To process a `POST` request, you only need to add `:- use_module(library(http/http_client)).` and use `http_read_data(Request, Data, [])` to obtain a list of `Var=Value` pairs in `Data`.  See also [`http_handler/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=http_handler/3) to simplify dispatching. Also, `[a,b|[]]` is the same as `[a,b]`.